# How I can prove this function is continuous only in 0?

Tags: calculus, continuity

How I can prove that $f(x)$ is continuous only at $x=0$?

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $x$ is Rational} \\
0, & \text{if $x$ is Irrational}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: **Hint:** Use the fact that both $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ are dense in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the sequential definition of continuity. Let $x_n$ be a sequence converging to $0$, then $f(x_n)$ is either $x_n$ or $0$ so $|f(x_n)| \leq |x_n|$ from which we see $f(x_n)$ converges to $0=f(0)$, which shows it is continuous at $0$. Now if $y$ is some nonzero real number, then $y$ is either rational or irrational. If $y$ is rational, then there is a sequence of irrational numbers $z_n$ such that $z_n \rightarrow y$. But $\lim f(z_n)=\lim 0 = 0$, while $f(\lim z_n)=f(y)=y \neq 0$. Similarly, if $y$ is irrational, we take $z_n$ to be a sequence of rational numbers converging to $y$ to get $\lim f(z_n)=\lim z_n = y$ and $f(\lim z_n)=f(y)=0$.